# Could you please let me know how I can retrieve ip addresses node under CDATA section and modify it using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, cdata

```
<con:request>
- <![CDATA[ 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cli="http://client.webservice.sepm.symantec.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cli:getComputersByIP>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <ipAddresses>10.211.36.63</ipAddresses>
         <!--Optional:-->

         <!--Optional:-->

      </cli:getComputersByIP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

  ]]> 
  </con:request>
```

this is the xml that i am using i need to replace the ip within the ipaddresses tag everytime so need to retrive it ,waiting for ur help 
thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

CDATA is not treated as markup. Therefore:

1. Extract the value of the `con:request` node (which will be a text node)
2. Parse it as XML
3. Use normal DOM methods on the new XML document

Comment: hi Quentin , i am new to vbscript and xml parsing could u please write the three steps provided in code form